# Javascript calculation without a negative number

Tags: javascript

How can I make sure that I don't get a negative number out of this code:

```
function reduction() {
  ctrlreduct.setValue(Number(ctrl1.getValue()) + Number(ctrl2.getValue()) - Number(ctrl3.getValue()));
};
```

I would like any negative number to default to zero.

Comment: `Math.max(0, x)`?

Comment: I guess `getValue` should do the parsing and `setValue` should do the clamping. No need to put the logic in `reduction` and all other functions that use these values.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an if decision...

```
if (( ctrlreduct.setValue(Number(ctrl1.getValue()) + Number(ctrl2.getValue()) - Number(ctrl3.getValue())) ) < 0 )
    {
        ctrlreduct.setValue(0) ;
    }
```

Comment: this makes a big assumption that `ctrlreduct.setValue()` returns the value. Be safer  to do the calc first

Comment: I have actually tried both ways, and it still returns a negative number when the values support it.

Comment: Yep that's the way he is calling the function if you look his question.
I dunno what exactly he did there ;)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I now have something that works:

```
function reduction() {
var test = (Number(ctrl1.getValue()) + Number(ctrl2.getValue()) - Number(ctrl3.getValue()));
ctrlreduct.setValue(Math.max(0,test));
};
```

Thx for the help :)